# Python serial communication with max 485

Tags: python, serial-port

I am using python to send serial data to max 485 
But I would like to view the binary data that python has sent and the max 485 has stored 
How do I do this ???

Comment: What have you tried? Posting the relevant code would give us something to start with. Couldn't you print the data (converted to hex) to a log file as it is written to the serial port. Don't know how to retrieve the stored data from the "max 485", but once you have the data, convert to hex and log. Then you can compare the logs.

Comment: I just want to know how many bits is the python sending  . For example for 0x01 , is python sending 4 bits or 8 bits or any other number of bits for that matter

Comment: So, do you have some code that shows how you are writing the serial data? I'd be surprised if it was anything other than 8-bits, are you using RS-485 or RS-232?

Comment: Il post the code in some time